# SmartCardProvisioning TPM security virtualsmartcard cryptography

Tags: c#, security, encryption, cryptography, tpm

I have a problem with TPM in windows app. I need to create TPM and use private key to encrypt a byte[] and public key to decrypt a byte[].

I utilized SmartCardProvisionin class and the method : RequestVirtualSmartCardCreationAsync(String,IBuffer,SmartCardPinPolicy) to create a virtual smart card.

how can I encrypt and decrypt a Byte[] throw the keypair in virtual smart card??

Comment: "throw"? Do you maybe mean "through"?

Comment: sorry, it's correct use through